Can I use "this figure" instead of "this percentage"?
I know "this percentage" or "this proportion" can be used because they refer to the variable of the proportion of the population under 14. I want to ask if this figure is correct? I'm worried that this figure may refer to the fixed figure 30% instead of the variable. However, a fixed number cannot decrease.

30% of the population was under 14 in 1960, However, this
figure/percentage/proportion had decreased to 15% by 2023. (I wrote
it.)


I don't understand this figure may refer to the fixed figure 30% instead of the variable. The "figure" is "30", which is very subtly different to "30%" (a "percentage", "proportion"). Your example doesn't feature anything that could usefully be referred to as a "fixed number" - quite the reverse, since the context clearly indicates that the value changes over time. But why are you asking the question? Why don't you want to just use the word "percentage"?

Rather than referring to that number in the report as a number in the report, you could refer to the real-world situation the numbers represent. "30% of the population was under 14 in 1960. By 2023 only 15% was below that age."

With your sentence, there's no real-world anchor: that figure, 15%, 2023 versus 2023, 15%,  that age.   "age" is a much more specific reference than "figure".

The question asks if figure is a correct alternative to percentage or proportion in this sentence:

30% of the population was under 14 in 1960, However, this figure/percentage/proportion had decreased to 15% by 2023.

It's not wrong, but it is ambiguous. As the comments have noted, you have multiple numbers in your first clause (30, 14, 1960). This in the second clause will refer back to the first clause, so when we hit the word figure, we wonder which number is being referred to. You resolve that uncertainty at the end of the sentence, because it's a number that has decreased, and the only decrease mentioned is the percentage. But if you use percentage, then we know all along what number you are referring back to.
So personally I would prefer percentage as the clearest term in this case.
It's worth noting that you miss the point when you say, "A fixed number cannot decrease." None of your numbers are variables. All of them are fixed. But they can all change. The fixed year 1960 changes to the fixed year 2023. The fixed percentage of 30 becomes a fixed percentage of 15. And so on.
If you're not clear about that, ask yourself this question: What was the percentage of the population under 14 in 1960? Answer: 30%. That percentage for that year remains the same, even though we have now reached 2023. So where is the change? It's not in the individual numbers or percentages. It is in the comparisons that are made between those numbers. And grammatically those changes are highlighted not by the numbers themselves but by the word decreased.
